# what happens during "writing to net"? (no replication, no external access)

Tags: mysql

one of our webservers acting up lately, queries are piling up etc...

we noticed that the mysql processes are a rather long time in the status "`writing to net`". I never witnessed this before (I'm no database admin, though...). Normally I see something like executing, writing to temp table, sending data....

this even happens with a simple php testscript on the same server, just a query like

```
SELECT * FROM old_unoptimized_middle_largish_myIsam_table
```

and a loop over the resultset.

Can someone tell me or point me to resources that explain what happens in this status? 
From the MySQL docs I would have thought that this status only applies to request that started from a remote server or during replication - but neither is the case here.
We do have set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 though, to allow access from other servers in the cluster.

I feel like a noob asking this, but our admin will be missing for quite some time and my google fu is failing...